# How to create a two column grid using CSS grid?

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm trying to create a fairly simple layout, and I want to avoid using floats. My simplified HTML is as follows, and so now I'm trying to create a two column layout, in which I would like to have item B on the left, and items A, C and D on the right (underneath eachother). The Code I tried using is:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'left right';
}

.item-b {
  grid-area: left;
}

.item:not(.item-b) {
  grid-area: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item item-a">A</div>
  <div class="item item-b">B</div>
  <div class="item item-c">C</div>
  <div class="item item-d">D</div>
</div>
```

But here, the items on the right are being placed on top of eachother. Is there any way to place them underneath eachother? Here is a fiddle with the same code: https://jsfiddle.net/b85h7g03/

Also, when you look at the fiddle, why are the items not 50% of the with of the container anymore?

(By the way, the reason I'm not placing item B above item A in my HTML, is because on mobile item B needs to be below item A)

Edit: I just updated my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b85h7g03/2/ I forgot to mention that item B has a flexible height and can get very long. For reference: This is the layout I want, but without floats: https://jsfiddle.net/hLx3709v/

Comment: you can use `grid-template-colums:1fr 1fr;`

Comment: You haven't defined any rows or columns.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go by using flex

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="children"></div>
  <div class="children"></div>
  <div class="children"></div>
  <div class="children"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.children {
  width: calc(50% - 10px);
  margin: 5px;
  background: #D8D8D8;
  flex: 1;
}
.children:first-child {
  flex: 0 0 calc(100% - 10px);
  border: 2px solid #44C0FF;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but not 100% what I need. The left area now doesn't seem to be able to get higher than the container, and also I would like to avoid setting a fixed height on my container.